# System.ArgumentNullException: missing source event info in MvxWeakEventSubscription

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

We are using data binding in our Xamarin.IOS project using MvvmCross(Hot Tuna version) as specified in the sample app “N-39-CrossLight-Touch”.

The sample app as well as our project works fine on simulator(IOS7) but on device(IOS7) it throws the below exception while binding.

> System.ArgumentNullException: missing source event info in
>   MvxWeakEventSubscription  Parameter name: sourceEventInfo  at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription2[System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs]..ctor
>   (INotifyPropertyChanged source, System.Reflection.EventInfo
>   sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler1 targetEventHandler) [0x00000] in
>   :0  at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxNotifyPropertyChangedEventSubscription..ctor
>   (INotifyPropertyChanged source, System.EventHandler1
>   targetEventHandler) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe
>   (INotifyPropertyChanged source, System.EventHandler1 eventHandler)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.MvxPropertyInfoSourceBinding..ctor
>   (System.Object source, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Leaf.MvxLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding..ctor
>   (System.Object source, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Leaf.MvxSimpleLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding..ctor
>   (System.Object source, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Construction.MvxPropertySourceBindingFactoryExtension.CreateLeafBinding
>   (System.Object source,
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyToken
>   propertyToken) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Construction.MvxPropertySourceBindingFactoryExtension.TryCreateBinding
>   (System.Object source,
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyToken
>   currentToken, System.Collections.Generic.List1 remainingTokens,
>   IMvxSourceBinding& result) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Construction.MvxSourceBindingFactory.TryCreateBindingFromExtensions
>   (System.Object source,
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPropertyToken
>   propertyToken, System.Collections.Generic.List1 remainingTokens,
>   IMvxSourceBinding& result) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Construction.MvxSourceBindingFactory.CreateBinding
>   (System.Object source, IList1 tokens) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Construction.MvxSourceBindingFactory.CreateBinding
>   (System.Object source, System.String combinedPropertyName) [0x00000]
>   in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.SourceSteps.MvxPathSourceStep.OnDataContextChanged
>   () [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.SourceSteps.MvxSourceStep.set_DataContext
>   (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.CreateSourceBinding
>   (System.Object source) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding..ctor
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder.BindSingle
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingRequest bindingRequest)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Binders.MvxFromTextBinder+<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription
>   description) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator102[Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription,Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.IMvxUpdateableBinding].MoveNext
>   () [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings
>   (IMvxBindingContextOwner view, IEnumerable1 bindings, System.Object
>   clearKey) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBindings
>   (IMvxBindingContextOwner view, System.Object target, IEnumerable1
>   bindingDescriptions, System.Object clearKey) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.AddBinding
>   (IMvxBindingContextOwner view, System.Object target,
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBindingDescription
>   bindingDescription, System.Object clearKey) [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBaseFluentBindingDescription1[MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField].Apply
>   () [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet2[CrossLightTouch.MyViewController,CrossLightTouch.ViewModels.MyViewModel].Apply
>   () [0x00000] in :0  at CrossLightTouch.MyViewController.ViewDidLoad ()
>   [0x0024f] in
>   /Users/admin/Downloads/N-39-CrossLight-Touch/CrossLightTouch/MyViewController.cs:81
>   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)  at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00008] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pp-UIWindow.g.cs:129 
>   at CrossLightTouch.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching
>   (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary
>   options) [0x00042] in
>   /Users/admin/Downloads/N-39-CrossLight-Touch/CrossLightTouch/AppDelegate.cs:25
>   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String
>   delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pp-UIApplication.cs:38
>   at CrossLightTouch.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008]
>   in
>   /Users/admin/Downloads/N-39-CrossLight-Touch/CrossLightTouch/Main.cs:17

By setting the IOS build options -> Link Behavior -> Don’t link , it works on device as expected, but the binary size has been doubled.

You can reproduce this issue with “N-39-CrossLight-Touch” sample.

Is there a fix or alternative for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with xamarin.ios/monotouch , mvvmcross and linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441506/trouble-with-xamarin-ios-monotouch-mvvmcross-and-linking)

Comment: Tried by adding this LinkerPleaseInclude.cs from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/nuspec/TouchContent/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs . It didn't worked.                   But when used mtouch arguments --linkskip=System and link behavior to Link SDK assemblies only it worked on device.                         The linker is not stripping any of my symbols , The sourceEventInfo is missing, which is internal to MvvmCross code. So fix should be part of MvvmCross code,  developers can include LinkerPleaseInclude.cs if any symbols of their code is optimized, that is not the case here i think.

Comment: What should be put in LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file to resolve this issue, instead of --linkskip=System ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already have a LinkerPleaseInclude file, copy the one from here into your project:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/6ab1baa9ca128921208efa994890039edf398474/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments/Example.Droid/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs

Also, add the following line to the `Include(TextView text)` method:

`text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;`

If that doesn't solve it, look for other events that may be used in the Mvx bindings and add those to the LinkerPleaseInclude file.

This issue is caused by the dynamic nature of Mvx binding on Android. Because the bindings are resolved at runtime, the Xamarin linker thinks the UI events they reference are not being used so they are removed from the final build. Adding references in the LinkerPleaseInclude file forces them to be included.

Comment: I upvoted this because in my case I used a workaround for textView (in the view did load - setting the text - which kind of defies the whole use of bind)